# Float numbers python 3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating

```
print ('%0.2f'+ % userUSD + '= %0.2f' + %Euro + 'Euro')
```

I'm using python 3.3 and while making a very simple currency converter I've stumbled upon this syntax error. Could you guys tell me how could I fix this and write the right way to print the floating point number in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error is because you're using both the `+` and `%` operators in a row. When you use `%` for string formatting, you don't want `+` in between the format string and its arguments.

So, the most basic fix would be to get rid of the extra `+` characters:

```
print ('%0.2f' % userUSD + '= %0.2f' % Euro + 'Euro')
```

However, it would probably make more sense to combine the format strings together, and do just one formatting operation:

```
print('%0.2f = %0.2f Euro' % (userUSD, Euro))
```

In new code though it's generally recommended to use the more capable `str.format` formatting system, rather than the `%` operator:

```
print('{:.2f} = {:.2f} Euro'.format(userUSD, Euro))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('%0.2f USD = %0.2f Euro' % (USD, Euro))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to write Python 3 formatted strings, using [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
print("{:0.2f} = {:0.2f} Euro".format(userUSD, Euro))
```

This breaks down to taking each positional value and formatting it with two decimal places, just like you would with `%` above.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('%0.2f USD = %0.2f Euro' % (USD, Euro))
```

The formatted string comes inside a single pair of quotations. The variables come then as a list after a % symbol.